# build x32 app on x64 host linux with using ./configure

Tags: c, linux, makefile, build, configure

I have elinks - console browser. I need to build it for x32 target system, I'm using ubuntu 16.04.1, I have already installed  gcc(g++)-multilib. I try to autogenerate make files using:

`../elinks-root/configure --build i686-pc-linux-gnu --host i386-pc-linux-gnu LDFLAGS="-static -m32" CFLAGS="-m32" LDXXFLAGS="-m32" CXXFLAGS="-m32"`

I need to get standalone binary, so build it with "-static" flag. And I can't handle error:

`relocatable linking with relocations from format elf32-i386 (button.o) to format elf64-x86-64 (lib.o) is not supported`

But lib.o doesn't located in my working directory, and either not in elinks's root directory.

Make version 4.1; GCC/G++ version 5.4.0.

UPD: I need to build it by myself, because I'll do some modifications and I'll rebuild it lots of times.

Comment: Does `../elinks-root/configure --help` list a `--static` option?  If so, then use that instead of passing `-static` among the `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: John, there is no such option

Comment: Ok.  I was focusing on the .o files being described as ELF objects -- which might still be a problem -- but there is also the issue that one is 32-bit and the other 64-bit.  It would be worthwhile trying to discover where and what this `lib.o` file is.  If it is not a product of the build you are trying to perform then you are probably picking up a 64-bit system library where you need a 32-bit one.

Comment: Well, I have no idea how to find out the file origin. But i have other builds for arm and x86-64, and there it is. But before my last test I deleted folders for that builds, so i can't really know from where this file came from.

Comment: There are 32bits `elinks` static builds here https://github.com/rkd77/elinks/issues/77 : `elinks-0.14.0rc2-i386.zip` (and elinks-0.14.0rc1-i586.zip ) both "one file apps", command = `./elinks` → opens OK with Ubuntu 16.04 .